# Argument of \text@ has an extra } \end{align*}

Tags: math-mode, align

Good day,

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amstext}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},font=small, margin=0.5cm]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left \{ NJ^{-1}T_d \right \}_\text{worst case}=\begin{bmatrix} 
0.0016  \\  
\pm 0.0003 \\  
0.0016  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I end up with the error:

```
*Argument of \text@ has an extra } \end{align*}*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `\tag` is meaningless inside a `bmatrix`

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of two tags now and put the first tag at the correct location. However, I still end up with the same error.

Comment: I only get the error "Multiple `\tag`"; can you make a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question. I forgot to include some of the packages.

Comment: Add braces around `\text{worst case}`. The package `breqn` redefines `_` so that it becomes compulsory using braces. Using `\}_{\text{worst case}}` solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of `breqn`. If you really want to use it (but I find it strange you use `align*` instead of the `breqn` environments), remember that it redefines many things. In particular, `_` has a meaning rather different from the usual one and the redefinition has the consequence that some constructs that are legal without it become illegal.

Add braces around `\text{worst case}`:

```
\[
\{ NJ^{-1}T_d \}_{\text{worst case}}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0.0016  \\  
\pm 0.0003 \\  
0.0016  
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

I've removed `\left` and `\right` that serve no purpose here; also a one line `align*` doesn't make sense. But these adjustments have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to work with very large equations, therefore I use dmath inside the breqn package.